# Состояние гонки и различие в записях в БД

Tags: flutter, race-condition, android-offline

Итак есть мобильное приложение разработанное на Flutter. Оно может читать данные с удаленного сервера и сохранять в своём локальном БД. Пользователь может офлайн просматривать, редактировать, удалять локальные данные и при подключении к сети они синхронизируются с удаленным сервером. Также есть  Web приложение подключенное к той же базе.

Проблема следующая:
Пользователь1 получил список вещей, отключился от сети, изменил имя вещь1. Пока он был офлайн пользователь2 через Web удалил вещь1. Когда пользователь1 подключается к сети его локальные данные пытаются обновить вещь1 но на сервере она уже удалена.

Кто как решал такие проблемы и есть ли какие нибудь Best Practice для этого случая?

Comment: Какое поведение должно быть? И какая БД?

Comment: @АртемЧерепахин у пользователя всегда должны быть возможности для редактирования и удаления сущности. на сервере БД Postgres на клиенте SQLite. Я просто хочу узнать лучшие практик для таких случаев, ответ от MiT мне кажется подходящим.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решать вам, отталкиваясь от типа приложения.

1. Либо создать заново `вещь1` из локальной БД в Web БД.
2. Либо удалить `вещь1` у `Пользователь1` локально, если его нет в Web БД.

Например, если это приложение связанно с документооборотом, то по идее главная БД в Web, тогда выбираем 2 вариант.

Comment: 3. Либо вывести пользователю сообщение о наличии конфликта правок и дать право выбора

Comment: Сразу видно человека,у которого общение с Git'ом на Ты) Спасибо за дополнение ответа!

Comment: Да БД на Web всегда главная. Думаю 2 способ наиболее подходящий, способ 3 не пойдет однозначно тк обьект должен быть удален раз и навсегда.